# eks http https redirect using ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

This is my ingress file , what I need is how to add https redirection settings here in ingress file , I did it using service file and it works but after to reduce costs I decided to use SINGLE ingress file which manage multiple services with SINGLE AWS CLASSIC load balancer.

```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      generation: 4
      name: brain-xx
      namespace: xx
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: app.xx.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: xx-frontend-service
              servicePort: 443
            path: /
    status:
      loadBalancer:
        ingress:
        - ip: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: What ingress controller are you using?

Comment: does it depend on the type of the load balancer that  I'm using  ? still I don't know which ingress controller I should use .. if it depends on the loadbalancer I'm using Classic load balancer . what do you think ?

Comment: Please take a look at: [Nginx Ingress force redirect](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect)

Comment: @DawidKruk I'll give a try , thanks a lot

Comment: @RA Let me know if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create `http` to `https` redirection on GKE. Let me know if this solution will work for your case on AWS:

**Steps to reproduce**

- Apply Ingress definitions
- Configure basic HTTP ingress resource
- Create SSL certificate
- Replace old Ingress resource with HTTPS enabled one.

### Apply Ingress definitions

Follow this [Ingress link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)  to check if there are any needed prerequisites before installing NGINX Ingress controller on your AWS infrastructure and install it.

#### Configure basic HTTP ingress resource and test it

Example below is Ingress configuration with HTTP traffic only. 
It will act as starting point:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-http
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xx.yy.zz
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: hello-port
      - path: /v2/ 
        backend: 
          serviceName: goodbye-service 
          servicePort: goodbye-port
```

**Please change this file to reflect configuration appropriate to your case.**

#### Create SSL certificate

For this to work without browser's security warnings you will need valid SSL certificate and a domain name.

To create this certificate you can use for example: [Linode create Let's Encrypt SSL certificates](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates/).

Let's Encrypt will create files which will be used later.

#### Configure HTTPS ingress resource and test it

By default Nginx Ingress will create a self-signed certificate if he's not provided one. To provide him one you will need to add it as a secret to your Kubernetes cluster.

As I said earlier the files (`cert.pem privkey.pem`) that Let's Encrypt created will be added to Kubernetes to configure HTTPS.

Below command will use this files to create secret for Ingress:

`$ kubectl create secret tls ssl-certificate --cert cert.pem --key privkey.pem`

This Ingress configuration support HTTPS as well as redirects all the traffic to it:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-https
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ssl-certificate
  rules:
  - host: xx.yy.zz 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: hello-port
      - path: /v2/ 
        backend: 
          serviceName: goodbye-service 
          servicePort: goodbye-port
```

**Please change this file to reflect configuration appropriate to your case.**

Take a look at this fragment which will enable HTTPS and redirect all the traffic to it:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ssl-certificate
```

Apply this configuration and check if it worked for you.

Below is part of curl output which shows that connecting to `http://xx.yy.zz` gives redirection to `https://xx.yy.zz`

```
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
< Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2019 15:06:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 177
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://xx.yy.zz/
```